# JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA cannot start completely

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss-eap-6

I have just set up a new workspace in Eclipse that uses an existing JBoss Run-Time environment (installation), and have also set up my maven web-project. Now I want to debug my project, therefore I deploy it on JBoss from within Eclipse. However, when I start JBoss from within Eclipse, it cannot start completely, but somehow  "freezes" in the middle of starting. These are the messages in the console:

09:32:36,672 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.2.0.Final-redhat-1
09:32:37,077 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
09:32:37,165 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8) startet

After the last message, nothing happens anymore. Can you help me?

Comment: you need to take a look at thread  dump of JBoss process to check why process is in hung state. You can capture thread dump using kill -3 command or through jstack utility.

Comment: @Abhijit, thank you! I will try this, as long as I have time.